# How to disable temporary IPv6 address in win7?

Tags: windows-7, ipv6, address, link-local

I found that the IPv6 link local address was generated randomly in Windows 7, not following the EUI-64 standard. Then I found [this link](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/304071-ipv6-temporary-address-enable-disable.html) and followed its guide:

```
netsh interface ipv6 set global randomizeidentifiers=disabled
netsh interface ipv6 set privacy state=disabled
```

However, after rebooting, I found the link local address was still generated randomly. How can I make Windows 7 use the EUI-64 standard?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up a Command Prompt in Administrator mode and run the following commands :

```
netsh interface ipv6 set privacy state=disabled store=active
netsh interface ipv6 set privacy state=disabled store=persistent
netsh interface ipv6 set global randomizeidentifiers=disabled store=active
netsh interface ipv6 set global randomizeidentifiers=disabled store=persistent
```

Each one should respond “Ok”.  If you didn’t launch the Command Prompt in Administrator, it will say the command required elevation.

Exit the command prompt, and reboot.

When your computer has rebooted, it should auto-configure itself using EUI-64 (based on the MAC address of the interface) within the subnet given in the router advertisement.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, the Modified EUI-64 format is no longer the standard (see [RFC8064](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8064)). That's why Windows and other operating systems have switched to using randomised identifiers by default. Also, temporary (privacy) addresses were standardised years ago by [RFC4941](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4941). So Windows does the right thing by default. It's fine to switch them off, but it does reduce your privacy protection.